# Unable to Debug, Load or Install any VSPackage

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn, vsix

I tried to create a *tool window* for visual studio 2013 Update2. I did `File->NewProject->Visual Studio Package` and inside the wizard I checked `Tool Window`. Then I pressed `F5` and I saw my tool window inside the **Exp** instance of VS under `View->OtherWindows`. Yeah, it is working!!!

Then I created a new package with proper names. Unfortunately at the moment I am not able to Debug, Load or even install the package on normal visual studio instance. Just nothing happens. No errors, no exceptions, no tool window option showing under `View->OtherWindows`. I can clearly see the package under `Tools->Extensions and Updates...`.

I tried to:

1. Uninstall and Install again
2. Clear all cache under `\AppData\~..~\Extensions\` and `\AppData\~..~\ComponentModelCache`
3. Create another package. May be I did > 20 packages with defaults
4. Restart PC
5. Clear all records in registry for already installed packages
6. All possible combinations of the steps above

What else I could try? Ideas?

PS: I forgot to mention that I have latest Roslyn installed.

Comment: Does both extensions have same name?

Comment: No :(. I just gave up. I guess if I reinstall everything will be OK. But this is overwhelming.

Comment: I know you deleted files under `..\extensions` but I generally just use **Start->Reset the Visual Studio 2013 Experimental Instance**